# What's the right way to do list dependency injection in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

If I have a number of services that all have the same interface, what is the right way to get them all using Angular injection without listing each one?

What I want to have is an array of services that is dependent on what js files are included into page -- so that I could transparently add/remove them by adding/removing files.

This is similar to list injection feature most of .NET (and Java?) DI frameworks provide.

In Angular/JavaScript (which does not have interfaces) I would see it working either by getting all services with the same name, or getting services by name regexp. Is this something I can do with Angular?

Comment: Check this answer I think it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/23838158/1959948

Comment: The only issue with the answer @Dalorzo linked to is that you still have to inject all your dependencies into the child service and pass them into the parent "class". To get around this you could just pass $injector into the parent class and let it inject whatever it needs.

Comment: @Dalorzo I do not think it answers my question -- how would it allow me to find all of the instances? They explicitly inject `'child'`.