# Angularjs Services, Factories, and Prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototypal-inheritance

From what I've read and tested, avoiding constructors and leveraging prototypical inheritance as much as possible has benefits. It's faster (not by much but I'm having to loop through +100,000's of items), allows for more flexibility, and is more native to JavaScript's philosophy.

My question then is how do you leverage an Angularjs Factory/Service to use prototypical inheritance rather than constructor logic suggested by the service?

Here is my example:

```
angular.module('components', [])
.service('Item', function() {
    var Item = function(val){
        this.func1 = function() {....};
        this.func2 = function() {....};
        this.func3 = function() {....};
         //... lots of functions
    }
    return Item; // @Flex, Forgot this, tnx
});

angular.module('main', ['components'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function(Item) {
    var items = [];
    _.each(largeArray, function(itm) { 
        items.push(new Item(itm));
    });
});
```

How can I change the service or factory to create items that inherit all functionality using prototypical inheritance instead? And since that's technically faster (I know not by much) & more native to the experience, why isn't it standard? Am I not understanding something about Angularjs?

Comment: I am not sure, but this might help: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html

Comment: I had a similar problem and was given a very helpful answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837863/extending-a-base-class-in-an-angular-service) that might also help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var Item = function(val){
    this.func1 = function() {....};
    this.func2 = function() {....};
    this.func3 = function() {....};
     //... lots of functions
}
```

you could use

```
var Item = (function(){
   var Item = function(val){
     // put attributes here not methods...
   }
   Item.prototype.func1 = function(){...};
   Item.prototype.func2 = function(){...};

   return Item;
})()
```

I think this is what you mean. This has nothing to do with angularjs though.. its just how you realize prototypical inheritance in a clean way.

Your example should do nothing btw, because you dont return anything from the service.

Comment: I don't think the IEFE is necessary though, Angular's `service` callback does that implicitly

Comment: @Bergi: its not necessary. Its just the style i like.

Comment: Also, i wouldnt say that prototypical inheritance is necessarily faster.. it just uses less memory. If you have a Singleton or something, there is no need to use prototypical inheritance..